# Numba nopython error with np.sum

Tags: python, numpy, numba

If I use this function

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def diss_matrix(data):
    n = data.shape[0]
    diss = np.empty((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            dist = np.absolute(data[i] - data[j]).sum()
            diss[i, j] = dist
            diss[j, i] = dist
    return diss

x = np.random.randn(100)
print(diss_matrix(x))
```

I get this error

```
numba.errors.UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'sum' of type float64
File "test_numba.py", line 11
[1] During: typing of get attribute at 
c:/Users/matte/Dropbox/Università/SDS/Thesis/source/test_numba.py (11)
```

I have been trying to understand what that means. The fact is, the instruction that triggers the error is the following

```py
dist = np.absolute(data[i] - data[j]).sum()
```

but I think the problem is that, somehow, `numba` assumes that `data[i]` and `data[j]` are `float64` and not arrays.
In fact, the following code

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def diss_matrix3():
    vec1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    vec2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
    dist = np.absolute(vec1 - vec2).sum()
    return dist
```

works flawlessly.

I'm using `numba 0.35` and I'm trying to find a way to make that function works. I know the existence of `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`, but I need to make my own implementation. Furthermore, the same error may occur in the future.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the shape of `np.random.randn(100)` it is `(100,)`, so `data[i]` is indeed a scalar, not an array. If you use `np.random.randn(100,100)` it should work. Have a look at the [docs for `randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) for a more detailed explanation of how the function works.

Comment: Thank you! I was desperate and didn't check such a basic thing. What misled me was the fact that it compiled with `nopython=False`.