# Numba compiler fails with np.sum?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a function that I want to accelerate using Numba (it computes the log-likelihood sum of residual given cov-var matrices, just for the context but **this is not important for the question**)

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def log_ll_norm_multivar(sigma, epsilon, mean=None) -> float:
    """
    This function computes the log-likelihood of a multivariate normal law applied to t observations of n size
    Args:
    sigma : the variance-covariance matrix, at each t, or constant. Must be ndarray(n,n) or ndarray(t,n,n)
            If it is (n,n), it will be copied at all times to have a (t,n,n)
    epsilon : ndarray(t, n) residuals
    Returns:
    float : Sum of the log likelihood of the residual, given the sigma variance-covariance matrices
    """

    t_max, n = epsilon.shape

    if sigma.shape == (n, n):
        sigma = np.array([sigma for _ in range(0, t_max)])

    if sigma.shape != (t_max, n, n):
        raise IllegalParameterException("Sigma shape must be t*n*n")

    if mean is None:
        mean = np.zeros((t_max, n))

    if mean.shape != (t_max, n):
        raise Exception("If provided, mean must be of shape (T,n)")

    epsilon_centered = epsilon - mean

    sum_det_sigma = np.sum(np.log(np.linalg.det(sigma)))
    inv_sigma = inv(sigma)
    third_term = np.array([
        epsilon_centered[t].transpose()
        .dot(inv_sigma[t])
        .dot(epsilon_centered[t])
        for t in range(0, t_max)
    ]).sum()

    return -1 / 2 * (t_max * n * log(np.pi * 2) + sum_det_sigma + third_term)
```

Numba fails to "compile" line `sum_det_sigma = np.sum(np.log(np.linalg.det(sigma)))` and says:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function sum at 0x10d1dfdc0>) found for signature:
 
 >>> sum(float64)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'sum': File: numba/core/typing/npydecl.py: Line 379.
    With argument(s): '(float64)':
   No match.
....

def log_ll_norm_multivar(sigma, epsilon, mean=None) -> float:
<source elided>
np.sum(np.log(np.linalg.det(sigma)))
```

After I debug the code without `@jit(nopython=True)`, it appears that `np.log(np.linalg.det(sigma))` is a np.array of shape(1000,), so we're not in the context of this post : [Numba nopython error with np.sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619855/numba-nopython-error-with-np-sum) where the data on which `np.sum` was applied was a scalar.

Just to be sure, I tried this code:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    arr_log = np.log(np.ones((1000,), dtype=np.float64))
    return arr_log.sum()
```

And it works perfectly.

What is going on with my code ?

Comment: If `Sigma` is 2d, then its `det` is a scalar, as is the `log`.

Comment: sigma is 3D (t, n,n), basically the cov-var matrix (2D) at all times giving a 3D tensor

Comment: Have you verified that - in the code?  `numba` docs says that the linalg code works for 1 and 2d.  Check the shape (or type) of `np.linalg.det(sigma)` by itself.

Comment: np.linalg.det(sigma) is 2D (determinant of each sigma, at all times). Maybe this might cause the problem ?

Comment: In `numpy` (and numba in python mode?) if `Sigma` is (...,M,M) shape, then the `det` will be (...) shape.  Is that true for numba in the no-python mode?

Comment: You were right ! There was a problem with the determinant not being of the right shape. Wondering why it showed up an error for the sum() though